# A better way to extract JSON value in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Can anyone suggest a better / neater way to extract the value from a Json pair than what I've got so far below pls...

My Json pair is

```
{"myKeyName":"myKeyValueVariableLength"}
```

is stored in myFile.txt and I just want the KeyValue (without quotes). What I've currently got is :

```
#!/bin/bash
PAIR=$(<myFile.txt)
IFS=': ' read -a arr <<< $PAIR
ONE="${arr[1]%?}"
TWO="${ONE%?}"
THREE=${TWO#'"'}
echo $THREE
```

This does work for me but I'm guessing there is a much neater way ? I have heard of jsawk but would like to try and do all within bash if possible.

Tks

Comment: could you use python?

Comment: If you are really looking for a "better/neater" way to do this, you should consider a scripting language, like Perl or Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash contains a built-in regex test, which takes the form `[[ string =~ regex ]]`. After it's run, captured sub-patterns are stored in an array called `$BASH_REMATCH`

It's a bit fussy / magic about handling quotes and escapes, so it took me a while to get working, but this seems to work:

```
PAIR='{"myKeyName":"myKeyValueVariableLength"}'
[[ $PAIR =~ ^\{\"([^\"]+)\":\"([^\"]+)\"\}$ ]] && echo "The key is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} and the value is ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

[Alternatively, do it The Unix Way, and invoke `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `python`, `php`, or whatever you have installed that will make your life easier. Something along the lines of `php -r "print_r( json_decode('"$PAIR"') );"` for instance...]

Answer (score 0):

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is designed for processing JSON:

```
jq -r '.myKeyName' myFile.txt
```